# Issues with tag synonyms: clang, llvm-clang, llvmclang

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I just saw a question on SO: [get pointer for CallInst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260871/get-pointer-for-callinst) which has been heavily tagged:

> llvm clang llvmclang llvm-clang

It seems rather clear to me that the latter 3 could be merged into a single one, in fact merging `llvmclang` and `llvm-clang` has already been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/llvmclang/synonyms) (I do not seem to have a high enough score to downvote it).

I tried to suggest merging `clang` and `llvmclang`, as well as `clang` and `llvm-clang`, and in both cases my request was denied.

- I cannot suggest `llvmclang` as a synonym for `clang` because it is itself a (suggested) master
- I cannot suggest `llvm-clang` as a synonym for `clang` because it is already a (suggested) synonym for `llvmclang`

I would appreciate if someone could step in and merge those 3 tags (preferably to the shortest tag...)

Comment: The proper form would be `llvm-clang` not `llvmclang`.

Comment: @agf: I would argue that the proper form is `clang` itself, because most of clang (short of the code generation modules) only rely on small utility tools hosted in LLVM.

Comment: I was just addressing which of those two would correctly point to the other the way tags are named, I wasn't making a judgement about whether `clang` should be separate from `llvm-clang`.

Comment: +1, I was looking at a question, with the llvmclang tag and then saw llvmclang and llvm-clang and thought shouldn't those just be clang; secondly llvmclang and llvm-clang do not have tag wikis while clang does and it has a good one at that.